# On the fly determination of selected columns in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I would like to select a comparative table of some summary data for three periods, if data is available.
E.g. today's sales results, yesterdays and the day before yesterday. Say on Monday data for Sun/Sat will not be available, as the shop was closed, and I want to not have a column for those days and I don't want to compare against Friday numbers.
I'm trying to achieve something along the lines of bellow (the syntax is wrong) in MSSQL:

```sql
SELECT
  t.MetricName,
  t.MetricValue AS [Today Value],
  IF @YesterdaysValuePresent THEN y.MetricValue AS [Yesterday Value],
  IF @DBYValuePresent THEN by.MetricsValue AS [DBY Value]
FROM
  myStoreMetrics(@Today) t
  LEFT JOIN myStoreMetrics(@Yesterday) y ON t.MetricName = y.MetricName
  LEFT JOIN myStoreMetrics(@DBY) y ON t.MetricName = by.MetricName
```

that would give 2 columns on Mondays, 3 columns on Tuesday and 4 on the rest of the weekdays.

Comment: Any *particular* query will always produce a result set with the same "shape" - the *number of columns*, their names and their types. You'll either have to go with dynamic SQL or (my usual preference) hide the detail at a more presentation-oriented level (application code or report builder)

Comment: Thanks, hiding on presenter-level is not an option in this particular case. I'm looking for some dynamic SQL solution, preferably, reasonably elegant :)